# Getting the user and the group apache is running as

Tags: php, apache

The **Apache** configuration below makes all **PHP** scripts to run as the user `www` belonging to the group `www`.

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User www
Group www
</IfModule>
```

I have tried the following:

- **User**: `<?php system('whoami'); ?>`
- **Group**: `<?php system('id -gnr $(whoami)'); ?>`

However, both are for **Linux** and **Mac** systems only. How can those values be retrieved for **Windows** systems also?

Using PHP, how to get the values of the `User` and the `Group` that Apache is running as?

Comment: call shell `whoami` from php ?

Comment: Yes `whoami` can show the **User** part, how about the **Group**?

Comment: Well, I don't remember the linux command to get the current group name, but this shouldn't be hard to find

Comment: I have tried `id -gnr $(whoami)` but I'm not sure if it's the correct one